# How to Enable gzip compression in aws s3 for files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My website speed is to slow. `GTMetrix` is telling me to **gzip** the files. But i hosted my files to aws s3. So, my question is

> > How can i enable gzip into aws?

Comment: [Serving Compressed Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html).  CloudFront in general will likely help.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801661/gzip-compression-on-static-amazon-s3-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GZIP Compression on static Amazon S3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801661/gzip-compression-on-static-amazon-s3-files)