# Does aws s3 put or sync use compression during transit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does aws s3 put or sync use compression during transmit? If not why?

It does not seem to be the case that cli does compression by default, also it seems there are no additional arguments that seem to be available to enable compression.

Given that all aws cli internally uses python sdk which in-turn uses http methods and that http allows for gzip headers, leveraged heavily in browsers, why is it that aws (in fact gcloud rsync seems similar in behavior) would choose not to compress

Comment: Someone else asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801661/gzip-compression-on-static-amazon-s3-files

Comment: *"It does seem to be the case that cli does compression by default."*  Why do you say this?

Comment: sorry typo 'not' is missing. I have added it.